# Django/Python strange no module named 'module_name'

Tags: python, django, django-models, import

i have created a simple module to store all my choices and reuse them in my application ( see CharField choices )

Here my project structure

```
project_name/  
  -- manage.py  
  -- settings.py
  -- ......
  -- apps/  
      -- __init__.py
      -- simple_app/
           -- __init__.py
           -- models.py
           -- ....
  -- common/
      -- __init__.py  
      -- choices/
           -- __init__.py
```

Inside my common.choices.__init__.py i have

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

SCALE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (1,_('Lineare')),
    (2,_('Logaritmica')),
    (3,_('Esponenziale'))
)

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('male',_('Maschio')),
    ('female',_('Femmina')),
    ('any',_('Tutti')),
)
```

and in apps.simple.models.py

```
from common.choices import SCALE_TYPE_CHOICES, GENDER_CHOICES
.....
```

my passenger_wsgi.py

```
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"path_to_my_project"))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"path_to_my_project/common"))

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project_name.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

In my dev server it works fine, but in my production server it throws and error "no module named choices"

manage.py shell

```
 import common
 print common
 <module 'common' from 'absolute_project_path/common/__init__.pyc'>
```

passenger_wsgi.py

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"path_to_my_project"))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"path_to_my_project/common"))

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project_name.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
 import common
 print common

 Outputs
 <module 'common' from 'absolute_project_path/common/__init__.pyc'>
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the directory the project is in to `sys.path`.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? my project is on sys.path and settings are imported correctly ( i think so )

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure there is no other package/module `common` in your sys.path.

```
import common
print common # or common.__file__
```

You are `append` project path to `sys.path` instead of `insert(0, path)`, thus an importable `common` in sys.path w/o choices will fail. You could use `insert` to see if the error goes away.

Comment: @Michael what's the output of `print common`?

Comment: my manage.py shell can import common ( after adding an sys.path.insert specifying the project path )

Comment: @Michael Does `from proj import common` work? The shell does not honor wsgi file also. Directly output `common.__file__` in wsgi and run server

Comment: @Michael  looks like a deeper circular-import. Does `common` imports anything relative to `apps`?

Comment: No absolutely ... the only import is the one i mention in my question ( see choices/__init__.py ), i use the file just to create some lists.

Comment: @Michael that's weird. What wsgi server do you use? Also remove `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"path_to_my_project/common"))
` line which is incorrect. And insert to pos 1 in `sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"path_to_my_project/")` instead of 0

Comment: I use mod_passenger on apache. it's a strange problem, until it's fixed i'll try to remove the choices to see if there are other problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove common from wsgi.py and add it to settings.py instead

```
import os
filedir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(filedir))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(filedir, 'common'))
```